# Does $E(XX^{\top})$ being full rank imply $E(XX^{\top}\mathbf{1}(Y\in A))$ being full rank?

Tags: probability, expected-value, singular-matrix, random-matrix

suppose $X=\begin{bmatrix}X_{1}\\X_{2}\end{bmatrix}$ is a discrete random vector with finite support, and $Y$ is a continuous random variable with finite support $[a,b]$, and $A$ is a subset of $[a,b]$ such that $Pr(Y\in A)>\delta>0$. Let $\mathbf{1}(\cdot)$ be the indicator function. My question is: does $E(XX^{\top})$ being full rank imply $E(XX^{\top}\mathbf{1}(Y\in A))$ being full rank?

Obviously, if $Y$ and $X$ are independent, the answer is yes, as $E(XX^{\top}\mathbf{1}(Y\in A))=E(XX^{\top})E(\mathbf{1}(Y\in A))$, which has full rank. What if $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1=\mathbf 1(Y\in A)$ be a Bernoulli variable with some probability $p>0$. And, let $X_2$ be a constant random variable that equals to $C$ with probability $1$. $\mathbb E[XX^T]$ is surely full rank. Let's check the other one:

$$\begin{align}M=\mathbb E[XX^T\mathbf 1(Y\in A)]&=\mathbb E[XX^TX_1]=\mathbb E \begin{bmatrix}X_1^3 & X_1^2X_2\\X_1^2X_2&X_1X_2^2\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

For this matrix to be full-rank, its determinant should be nonzero:
$$\begin{align}\det M &= \mathbb E[X_1^3]E[X_1]E[X_2^2]-E[X_1^2]^2E[X_2]^2\\&=p^2C^2-p^2C=0\end{align}$$

So, there is no guarantee that the suggested expression is full-rank.

Comment: Thanks! What about the reverse of the statement? Does $E(XX^{\top}\mathbf{1}(Y\in A))$ being full rank imply $E(XX^{\top})$ being full rank?

Comment: I couldn't think of an immediate counter-example to disprove. So, suspecting it can be true. You can ask it as another question (in another topic) to get others' opinions.